# Convert CONLL file to a list of Doc objects

Tags: spacy

Is there a way to convert CONLL file into list of `Doc` objects without having to parse the sentence using the `nlp` object. I have a list of annotations that I have to pass to the automatic component that uses `Doc` objects as input. I have found a way to create the doc:

```
    doc = Doc(nlp.vocab, words=[...])
```

And that I can use the `from_array` function to recreate the other linguistic features. This array can be recreated by using index value from `StringStore` object, I have successfully created Doc object with LEMMA and TAG information but cannot recreate HEAD data. My question is how to pass HEAD data to Doc object using from_array method.

The confusing thing about the HEAD is that for sentence that has this structure:

```
Ona 2
je 2
otišla 2
u 4
školu 2
. 2
```

The output of this code snippet:

```
from spacy.attrs import TAG, HEAD, DEP
doc.to_array([TAG, HEAD, DEP])
```

is:

```
array([[10468770234730083819,                    2,                  429],
       [ 5333907774816518795,                    1,                  405],
       [11670076340363994323,                    0,  8206900633647566924],
       [ 6471273018469892813,                    1,  8110129090154140942],
       [ 7055653905424136462, 18446744073709551614,                  435],
       [ 7173976090571422945, 18446744073709551613,                  445]],
      dtype=uint64)
```

I cannot correlate the center column of the from_array output to dependency tree structure given above.

Thanks in advance for the help,

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I finally cracked it it appears that head - index if the index is lower than head and 18446744073709551616 - index otherwise. This is the function that I used if anyone else needed it:

```
import numpy as np
from spacy.tokens import Doc
docs = []
for sent in sents:
    generated_doc = Doc(doc.vocab, words=[word["word"] for word in sent])
    heads = []
    for idx, word in enumerate(sent):
        if word["pos"] not in doc.vocab.strings:
            doc.vocab.strings.add(word["pos"])
        if word["dep"] not in doc.vocab.strings:
            doc.vocab.strings.add(word["dep"])
        if word["head"] >= idx:
            heads.append(word["head"] - idx)
        else:
            heads.append(18446744073709551616-idx)
    
    np_array = np.array([np.array([doc.vocab.strings[word["pos"]], heads[idx], doc.vocab.strings[word["dep"]]], dtype=np.uint64) for idx, word in enumerate(sent)], dtype=np.uint64)
    generated_doc.from_array([TAG, HEAD, DEP], np_array)
    docs.append(generated_doc)
```

Comment: The heads in `doc.to_array()` are relative rather than absolute heads and then they're cast to `uint64`, so negative heads (head to the left rather than to the right) end up looking like this here.

Comment: @aab thanks for the response, yes exactly :-) , although I didn't find any documentation on this subject.

Comment: No, this is more of an internal method. The typical way is to create a `Doc` with `words` and `spaces` (you can use `get_words_and_spaces` from `spacy.util` if you have `words` and `text`) and then set the properties on the `Doc` directly as in `doc[3].head = doc[2]` or `doc[10].tag_ = "ABC"`.

Comment: The upcoming spacy v3 will have more conversion methods that convert to `Doc`. A preview of the full-fledged CoNLL-U converter is here, with some extra handling of NER in the MISC column and merging of multi-word tokens: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/1f4930086209128876e2804ae070ded54471e6f2/spacy/training/converters/conllu_to_docs.py

Comment: Dear @aab, didn't know that I could add properties directly, I had some notion in head that docs are somewhat immutable. Thank you very much for the tips :-)